# Recording audio in android

Tags: java, android

I want to record own voice or any through mic(In any way) into a file in my project and want to read later and listen to it.How can i do this? Anyone reply me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html

About 3/4 the way down the page you'll see

Performing Audio Capture
Audio capture from the device is a bit more complicated than audio and video playback, but still fairly simple:

Create a new instance of android.media.MediaRecorder.

Set the audio source using MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(). You will probably want to use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC. 

Set output file format using MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(). 

Set output file name using MediaRecorder.setOutputFile(). 

Set the audio encoder using MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(). 

Call MediaRecorder.prepare() on the MediaRecorder instance. 

To start audio capture, call MediaRecorder.start(). 

To stop audio capture, call MediaRecorder.stop(). 

When you are done with the MediaRecorder instance, call MediaRecorder.release() on it. 
Calling MediaRecorder.release() is always recommended to free the resource immediately.

Followed by code showing exactly how to store audio input and play it back, hope this helps. (I tried to paste the code here but pasting from android's guides is difficult)

Comment: Thanks Andrew.Is it compulsory to call MediaRecorder.release() ?

Comment: Recommeneded, there really isnt any reason not to call it though. You can always just enable the recorder again next time its needed

Comment: I will try this in office tomorrow,If i will get anything wrong then i will put my code and contact you.Thanks mate for this valuable information.

Comment: I checked it.I already saw it but didnot see the actual code below.I will implement it and check it tomorrow morning in my office and let you know of the result.thanks

Comment: Hi andrew I am giving path as  recordPath=getResources().getResourceName(R.raw.a);(where recordPath is a String variable and a is present as a.wav file in raw folder which is inside resource folder).It is showing FileNotFoundException.Anything wrong i am doing?

Comment: Go to the link in the original post, scroll all the way to the bottom. That code is exactly what you need.

Comment: Did you recognize that while recording and performing and outgoing phone call that outgoing audio is muted?